# How to pass a JSON object inside a QTextEdit

Tags: json, qt, c++11, qt5, qtextedit

I have a small GUI that I use to load/save `json` configuration files, the most important parameters are in the gui below:

![conf]

[image]

**The problem** I have been trying to solve is that I am not able to create an object inside a `QTextEdit` and am not sure why despite I am following [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText) on how to do that.

Below a snippet of code both for the load and save button.
Also for the sake of brevity I only kept how I did the spinbox and, of course, the textedit:

```
void SettingsForm::on_loadBtn_clicked()
{
  // Opening file dialog....

  if(listDocksConfig.isEmpty())
  {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Message"), tr("Please Open Configuration"));
  }
  else
  {
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject obj;
    QByteArray data_json;
    QFile input(listDocksConfig);
    if(input.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
      data_json = input.readAll();
      doc = doc.fromJson(data_json);
      obj = doc.object();

      const double xposValue = obj["X Pos"].toDouble();
      QTextEdit textEdit     = QTextEdit::setText(obj["comments"]);  // <- Error Here

      ui->doubleSpinBox_XPos->setValue(xposValue);
      ui->textEdit->setText(textEdit);      // <- Error Here
    }
    else
    {
       // do something
    }
  }
}

void SettingsForm::on_saveBtn_clicked()
{

  // saving configuration with file dialog....

  if(listDocksConfig.isEmpty())
  {
    // do something...
  }
  else
  {
    const double xposValue = ui->doubleSpinBox_XPos->value();
    QTextEdit textEdit     = ui->textEdit->setPlainText();  // <- Error Here

    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject obj;

    obj["X Pos"] = xposValue;
    obj["comments"] = textEdit.toString();     // <- Error Here

    doc.setObject(obj);
    QByteArray data_json = doc.toJson();
    QFile output(listDocksConfig);
  }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1. I consulted the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText) on how to solve this problem, but could not figure out why that was not working. I also went ahead and try to use an alternative such as [setText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText) but still no luck.
2. I came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395369/how-to-add-object-to-json-file) which I used as guidance for my example and solved almost all problems but the `QTextEdit` one.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117148/how-to-create-json-object-using-string) additional post was useful but still couldn't solve the problem.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is wrong!!

```
QTextEdit textEdit = ui->textEdit->setPlainText();
```

1. setPlainText() needs const QString &text as parameter
   you cant do that, read the [official doc here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText)
2. the method is void, ie. it returns nothing so you can not use void to init a `QTextEdit` object

---

update:

you already have a textEdit in the layout, so no reason to redefine one...

you can do:

```
ui->textEdit->setPlainText(obj["comments"].toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading the question. The error starts at the beginning of the line `QTextEdit textEdit = QTextEdit::setText(obj["comments"]);` and the error says: `error: no matching function for call to ‘QTextEdit::setText(QJsonValueRef)’
       QTextEdit textEdit = QTextEdit::setText(obj["comments"]);
`

Comment: Do you see something I don't see?

Comment: @Emanuele yes i see the issue,... but then the code you posted was not the correct one...

Comment: @Emanuele I updated my answer with the json value... give a try and update me

Comment: Yes that worked :) Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: my pleasure!! :)

Comment: @Emanuele dont forget to upvote my post.... and accept the answer too :)

Comment: Yes, I always do it, I have to wait because I can vote again in 6 hours. :)